# MX2 recovery problem

Tags: recovery-mode

I'm hoping someone can help me with the problem I have.
I have a MX2 Android TV Box and flashed it with Matricom firmware, running 4.2.2. When I try to access the SD card in recovery mode it doesn't allow me to do this -
Apply from EXT,  update from SD card, then it's blank. I've formatted several times and confirmed the files are there but they don't show in recovery.
When I open Winzip/File manager on the box I can see my files there. 
I want to flash the box again but can't from SD because the files won't show.
I'm not sure what to do with 'Update from ADB', (is this an option)?.

I don't have a lot of knowledge with these things but want to learn if someone can help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sideloading (usually seen as `apply update from ADB`) is a form of `adb push` wherein the ZIP file, say `ROM.zip`, will automatically get flashed by the recovery once ADB finishes copying it to the phone. The command you use on the PC is

`adb sideload <file.zip>`

Chances are if you're using a stock recovery (see if it says `3e` at the top of the recovery screen), only official ZIPs from the manufacturer will get through verification; whereas third-party ZIPs will stall at `Installation aborted.`

But if you're using CWM (or another custom recovery), you can pretty much `sideload` anything you want.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  It does say 3e at the top of the screen.. Guess I should download CWM first then. Any reason why the sd card won't work in recovery?

Comment: I'm not sure about that myself, because I've seen the same behaviour on my brother's phone. Maybe it only sees specifically named zips?

Comment: @user61388 Wait, do you by any chance have your ZIPs on an external SD? A Google search told me that 3e does not mount external SDs

Comment: Yes. I copied my .zip file onto it from the laptop and plugged it in the side. Sounds like that's the problem then. Any other way I can flash the firmware in recovery apart from External SD?

Comment: I should add the .zip file I'm trying to flash I have used on the box before so I know it does work... not too familiar with adb but will use that if that's an option?

Comment: That *is* an option :D Connect it via USB, wait for the drivers to get installed, then `adb sideload` away!

Comment: I connected the box to my laptop and nothing was detected. Device manager didn't find the box either.

Comment: Make sure you're actually in the sideloading mode before connecting it to the PC. Use the original cable, switch ports if necessary.